# c# Can't get the value of a variable outside of the while loop

Tags: c#, string, loops, variables, while-loop

I have a while loop inside of a foreach loop.
Inside of my while loop the description variable return data but outside the loop it's empty
I'm new on c# so I don't fully understand why, can you help me please ?

Here is the code :

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
    // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element
    // of the array is one line of the file.
    string[] logs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    string[] confFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(this.confPath);
    string description;

    // read each line of the log file
    foreach (string log in logs)
    {
        if (log.Contains("ERROR"))
        {
            nextLine = index + 1;
            descriptionLine = index + 2;
            var firstLine = log;
            var secondLine = logs[nextLine];
            description = logs[descriptionLine];



            while (description.Contains("at") || description.Contains("---"))
            {
                description = logs[descriptionLine++];

            }

            if (!confFile.Any(s => s.Contains(secondLine)))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(this.confPath))
                {

                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", firstLine, secondLine, description));

                }
            }

        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to investigate. I strongly recommend to check if `descriptionLine++` will be out of bounds before assigning `description = logs[descriptionLine++];`, but that is probably not your actual problem here.

Comment: The only possibility that `description` becomes an empty string, is that `logs` contains an empty string and all lines before that either contain `"at"` or `"---"` (or you run out of bounds, but then an exception will be thrown)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you modify the while loop condition while still looping, and the variable assignment is made before the index increment.

```
description = logs[descriptionLine++];
```

This makes the loop check for the condition of the *previous line content* while modifying the content of description with the current iteration.

Let's suppose your `logs[]` is made of these 3 simple lines and we start with `descriptionLine = 0`:

```
line 0: blah blah at blah
line 1: blah blah at blah
line 2: something else
```

now,

```
description = logs[0] // "line 0: blah blah at blah"
```

Let's see the while loop condition:

```
while (description.Contains("at") || description.Contains("---")) { ... }
```

The condition is satisfied because description momentarily contains the word "at", and we get in the loop body:

```
description = logs[descriptionLine++];
```

The postponed `++` increment operator you used makes the `descriptionLine` variable evaluated **first** and **then** incremented. This means that the assignment to the `description` variable is made *before* the `descriptionLine` value is incremented from `0` to `1`.

Now (this is important) we get out of the first loop into the second with an **unchanged** `description`. When we start the second iteration, the value of `description` is still the same so we get into the loop body, but the `descriptionLine` value had been incremented from `0` to `1`. The postponed `++` increment operator makes the trick again:

```
description = logs[1] // "line 1: blah blah at blah"
```

but when we get out of the loop, `descriptionLine` is 2. Finally, we get into the third and last iteration

```
while (description.Contains("at") || description.Contains("---"))
```

`description` is `"line 1: blah blah at blah"`, we get into the body but we're at the third iteration, we shouldn't have gotten in! Instead, this happens:

```
description = logs[2] // "line 2: something else"
```

We make another assignment, since now `descriptionLine` has been incremented from `1` to `2`.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, whether you do a preincrement or postincrement on `descriptionLine`, it will still iterate all of the values and the loop will stop, once `description` has a value, that doesn't fulfill the loop condition anymore. The only difference is, that it will inspect the first value twice

Comment: @derpirscher assuming you can immediately get into the loop, `description = logs[++i]` will be different from `description = logs[i++]`, changing the condition to get into the second iteration.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make any (noteable) difference. Because the only thing that happens with `description = logs[i++]` is, that `description` is assigned the same value twice and thus, the first value will be checked twice if it contains `"at"` or `"---"`. The loop will still stop at the first `description` not meeting the loop condition. And for the code after the `while` loop, the value of `descriptionLine` is not relevant anymore ...